# Multiple used archives for database connection causing a CoreException in JPA Tools in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, jpa, database-connection, postgis

I'm using EclipseLink to create tables from entities in Eclipse. Therefore I do a right click on my project --> JPA Tools --> Generate Tables from Entities --> Database.

This results in the an error. The log description is attached underneath.

The trace stack explains, that the referenced archive hasn't been found. Actually I'm using two archives and somehow eclipse, eclipselink or the database connection handler is doing something wrong.

I'm using PostGIS and PostgreSQL. The archives are retrieved through maven. The names are postgis-jdbc-2.2.1.jar and postgresql-42.0.0.jar. They are both present and working. Establishing a connection is also possible through the JPA properties tab of my project in eclipse.

My current workaround is to use just PostgreSQL driver (org.postgresql.Driver) without the additional archive instead of the PostGIS driver (org.postgis.DriverWrapper / DriverWrapperAutoProbe) with both archives.

Did anyone encounter this problem before? Does anyone have a solution?

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.ui 4 0 2017-03-26 13:36:22.256
>   !MESSAGE An error occured during launch
>   !STACK 0
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured during launch
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.gen.AbstractJptGenerator.saveAndLaunchConfig(AbstractJptGenerator.java:315)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.gen.AbstractJptGenerator.generate(AbstractJptGenerator.java:120)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui.gen.AbstractJptGenerateJob.generate(AbstractJptGenerateJob.java:136)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.common.ui.gen.AbstractJptGenerateJob.runInWorkspace(AbstractJptGenerateJob.java:73)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: The archive: C:/Users/mmce/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.0.0/postgresql-42.0.0.jar;C:/Users/mmce/.m2/repository/net/postgis/postgis-jdbc/2.2.1/postgis-jdbc-2.2.1.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.abort(JavaRuntime.java:1408)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.abort(JavaRuntime.java:1393)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.resolveRuntimeClasspathEntry(JavaRuntime.java:957)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.addStandardClasspathEntries(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.resolveClasspath0(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider$1.call(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:114)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider$1.call(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:1)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
>       at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.launch.MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.resolveClasspath(MavenRuntimeClasspathProvider.java:111)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.RuntimeClasspathProvider.resolveClasspath(RuntimeClasspathProvider.java:65)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaRuntime.resolveRuntimeClasspath(JavaRuntime.java:1260)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.getClasspath(AbstractJavaLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:412)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JavaLaunchDelegate.launch(JavaLaunchDelegate.java:72)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
>       at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.jpt.common.core.internal.gen.AbstractJptGenerator.saveAndLaunchConfig(AbstractJptGenerator.java:312)
>       ... 5 more

Comment: you put some entry in some config somewhere as `C:/Users/mmce/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.0.0/postgresql-42.0.0.jar;C:/Users/mmce/.m2/repository/net/postgis/postgis-jdbc/2.2.1/postgis-jdbc-2.2.1.jar` but that should be a single jar. i.e the separator is wrong. Where did you put that?!

Comment: In Eclipse you can create a Database Connection. While you're creating editing this connection you can choose a driver (int the connection properties, define it's properties as well and add one or multiple jars for it. So I didn't added this to a property file, eclipse or the jpa tool framework in eclipse did.